# How can deploy automated test program in Android

Tags: android, deployment, automated-tests, robotium

I need to deploy my automated test program and ensure manual test team can use it.My solution is write a desktop UI program and install apk,switch language,switch versions,select test cases.Then i can make my test program easy to use anyone who doesnt know code.But if i do this , it takes long time.

Is there anyone have similar experience or provide easier solutions, frameworks to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need an apk with `Robotium` tests inside use `Gradle` tasks like `connectedDebugAndroidTest`.

To create just an apk file use `assembleDebug`. Generated '.apk's you would find in this directory: `{app-name}/app/build/outputs/apk`.

Read also about `Continuous Integration` and its tools like `Jenkins`or `Travis`(which is free for open-source project on GitHub) to make generating `.apk` files more automated.

Hope I answer your question. If `no`, please free to describe what I missed.